# Array lengths differ?

Tags: java, eclipse

My task is to create a method that takes as input an array of floating point numbers as doubles representing salaries and returns an array of salaries with each salary increased by 5%.

My Code so far is:

```
public double[] salaryIncrease(double[] salary) {
    double tax = .05;
    double[] total_tax = { (salary[0] * tax) + salary[0], (salary[1] * tax) + salary[1], (salary[2] * tax) + salary[2] };
    return total_tax;
```

However, running this code results in the error message:
`array lengths differ, expected :<5> but was: <3>`

What is the error in my code and how can I fix it?

PS.

Input: salaries [23000.50, 25478.66, 78496.50]

Output: New salaries [24150.525, 26752.593, 82421.325]

Comment: Your code hardcodes an array of length 3, regardless of input size. If you only test it with an input size of 3, the code appears to work correctly, but it's still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine on my machine (Java 12):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test
{
    public static double[] salaryIncrease(double[] salary) {
        double tax = .05;
        double[] total_tax = { (salary[0] * tax) + salary[0], (salary[1] * tax) + salary[1], (salary[2] * tax) + salary[2] };
        return total_tax;
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            double[] input = {23000.50, 25478.66, 78496.50};

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(salaryIncrease(input)));
        }

    } 
}
```

While your code works in this case, it could be improved by taking into account the general case, where the array has more or less than three elements. To achieve this, you could modify your method as follows:

```
public static double[] salaryIncrease(double[] salary) {
        double tax = .05;
        double[] total_tax = new double[salary.length];
        for(int i=0;i<salary.length;i++)
        {
            total_tax[i] = salary[i]*(1.0+tax); 
        }
        return total_tax;
    }
```

Using streams, you could even code this function as a one-liner:

```
public static double[] salaryIncrease(double[] salary) {
    return Arrays.stream(salary).map(s->s*1.05).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a good practice would be to initialize the size of the resulting array based on the size of the source array passed as paremeter to the method eg :

```
public static double[] salaryIncrease(double[] salary) {
        double tax = .05;
        double[] total_tax = new double[salary.length];  
        for (int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++) {
            total_tax[i] = salary[i] * tax + salary[i];
        }
        return total_tax;
}
```